# Robot picks up trash problem: how to reduce my time consuming by using dynamic programming

Tags: c

Robot picks up trash
topic description
In a room with n*m tiles, some tiles have litter on them to pick up. Now there is a robot that can pick up garbage starting from the upper left tile, and can only go right or down each time. Every time he fully reaches a tile point, he will automatically pick up the garbage on this tile. Q: How much garbage can be picked up at most.

enter description
Multiple sets of input, the first line of each set contains two integers n and m, and the next n lines and m columns represent the garbage distribution on the tiles (1<=n,m<=200)

output description
For each set of inputs, output an integer representing the maximum amount of garbage that can be picked up.

sample input
6 7

0 1 0 1 0 0 0

0 0 0 1 0 1 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 1 0 0 1

0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 1 0

Note: 1 means there is garbage, 0 means there is no garbage.

sample output
5

this is my code :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int max(int a, int b) {
    if (a > b) {
        return a;
    }
    else {
        return b;
    }
}
int f(int n,int m,int v[][100],int sum) {
     
    if(v[n][m]!=0){
        sum = sum + 1;
    }
    if (n == 0&&m==0) {
        return sum;
    }

    else if(n != 0 && m != 0) {
        return max(f(n - 1, m, v,sum) , f(n, m - 1, v,sum));
    }
    else if(n == 0) {
        return f(n, m - 1, v,sum);
    }
    else {
        return f(n - 1, m, v,sum);
    }
    
}
int main() {
    int sum=0, n, m, v[100][100] = {0},i,j,x;
while (scanf("%d%d", &n, &m) != EOF) {
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        for (j = 1; j <= m; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &x);  
            if (x == 1)
                v[i][j] = 1;
            else
                v[i][j] = 0;
        }
            
sum = f(n, m, v,sum);
printf("%d\n", sum);
    }
    
}
```

I just try to recursion ,but time limited error ,so I want to memorize my result to reduce time consuming .

Comment: You could try Dijkstra, a form of BFS, for your "weighted graph", which requires a single pass of the data. Getting past the Time Limit Error is actually *part of the problem*, not "but for that I would have solved it!"

Comment: The amount of garbage that can be picked up starting at the bottom right corner (row n−1, column n−1) is the amount of garbage at that spot. The amount of garbage that can be picked up starting at any other tile in the bottom row is the amount of garbage at that spot plus the amount of garbage that can be picked up starting at the tile to its right. The amount of garbage that can be picked up starting at any other tile in the rightmost column is the amount of garbage at that spot plus the amount of garbage that can be picked up starting at the tile below it…

Comment: … The amount of garbage that can be picked up starting at any other tile is the amount of garbage in that spot plus the greater of the amount of garbage that can be picked up starting at the tile below it or the amount of garbage that can be picked up starting at the tile to its right. So all you need to do is create a new array (or use the original) to fill in the bottom right corner with that amount, then the bottom row, then the right column, and then the remaining spaces in a “reverse order” (working from bottom right to top left).

Comment: E.g., change `f` to `{ for (int c = m-2; 0 <= c; --c) v[n-1][c] += v[n-1][c+1]; for (int r = n-2; 0 <= r; --r) v[r][m-1] += v[r+1][m-1]; for (int r = n-2; 0 <= r; --r) for (int c = m-2; 0 <= c; --c) v[r][c] += max(v[r+1][c], v[r][c+1]); return v[0][0] }`.

Comment: Incidentally, when the problem description says “1<=n,m<=200”, do not declare your arrays as `v[100][100]` or `v[][100]`. In most numbering systems, 100 is less than 200.

Comment: I note that the DP-styled approach Eric describes is closely analogous to a BFS (starting at the bottom right), such as WeatherVane describes.